# Does field datatype affect the sql query speed?

Tags: mysql, sql

- I have already made index and all things to increase the sql query speed.I found one thing related to table desgin : field datatype for it.
- **when i am using mediumtext datatype at that time sql is slow but when i am using varchar(5000) datatype  speed is increase compare to
  above.**
- can you please tell me which datatype mediumtext ,varchar(5000)  is
  better?
- can you please tell me enum datatype decrease the query speed?

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the matter is in the amount of space required to store the data-types in the schema, and ensuring that the data-type choice matches the data being stored without incurring any unnecessary overhead.

> Depending on the data types, yes, it does make a difference.

References :

**[For databases, does choosing the correct data type affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623082/for-databases-does-choosing-the-correct-data-type-affect-performance)**

[**Performance and datatype**](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/how-can-data-type-choice-affect-performance/)

[**SQL server performance**](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/datatypes/)

[**Datatypes Matter**](http://thomaslarock.com/2012/08/why-datatypes-matter-3-ways-they-can-hurt-performance/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes data type does matter. Its always adviced to use proper datatype for columns to improve performance. It will help performance of DB while retriving records.

Follow the below links:
http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/Creating-SQL-Server-columns-A-best-practices-guide

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-plus-tips-for-getting-the-best-performance-out-of-your-sql-server-data-types/